# Loop through each column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with n columns and I am trying to create a function which recurses through the columns.

for instance say I have the following data frame:

```
| left | center | right |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| One  | Two    | Three |
```

I want to run a function that uses the left column and then left and center column and then left, center and right column. So basically, at each step, I am using the prior columns + 1. Is there an efficient way in pandas to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1,df.shape[1]):
  print(df[df.columns[0:i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the function you have in mind is something commutative (like addition or multiplication), there probably isn't any really efficient way to do this.

That said, one method is to write a function that operates on all the columns in a dataframe, and then do what cristelaru vitian suggested, and run that function in a loop where you feed it first at dataframe with one column, then a dataframe with two columns, etc.

```
for i in range(1,df.shape[1]):
  your_function(df[df.columns[0:i]])
```

This should be fairly efficient if the function you are using takes advantage of array vectorization (this includes a lot of pandas and numpy functions), but will be fairly slow otherwise.

If you are writing a custom function that takes in one row of data, you can use the DataFrame.apply function to apply your custom function to each row in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way I can imagine:

```
for column in df:
    my_function(df.loc[:,:column])
```